# Best Architecture for communication between Central JBOSS Server and n Remote JBOSS Servers

Tags: jboss

In our product we have one central server at Data Center where all services are hosted in a JBOSS server clustered mode and need to deploy n remote servers at customer premises with a subset of services hosted on JBOSS server for local processing. All Remote Servers need to communicate only with Central Server. After processing the information at Remote Server information/result will be send to Central Servers. I am thinking of using ESB (JBOSS switchyard or Mule ESB)for this architecture. please let me know what would be the right architecture for this deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ESB will be a good option as
a) It will fullfil the Security requirement as interact with outer world (remote server in your case)
b) Provide Data ,Protocol transformation if required
c) you can orchestrate the process (the order in which you want to call the services)
d) Monitoring

You can consider using Fuse ESB too.(Red Hat has bought it so better than existing JBoss ESB )

Comment: Thanks Maverick. Will try with ESB. Due u see any other option for this requirement?

Comment: 1) Assuming that the remote server needs to communicate with Central server through some Service (Rest/SOAP) and the security and Failover requirements are taken care ,they can communicate directly too over the web.

Comment: Yeah but the problem with this is if the communication fails we will loose the request. But with ESB in place with durable message its always ensures delivery of request and response.

Comment: i agree..for this reason ESB is a better option